# scroll function not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a jQuery scroll function set up, that when the user scroll beyond 94px the `.fixed-header-wrap` fades in and there's a class change etc too. This function isn't working on IE browsers though, and the `.fixed-header-wrap` is showing on document load and not fading out / in etc. My markup below:

```
//Header Colour Scroll Function

var scroller = true;
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(".sector-menu").css('display') == 'none') {

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 94 && scroller) {

            $('.fixed-header-wrap').addClass('header-shadow');
            $(".fixed-header-wrap").fadeIn('fast');
            $('.header-logo').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.header-wrap').addClass('header-blue');

            scroller = false;

        } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 94 && !scroller) {

            $(".fixed-header-wrap").removeClass('header-shadow');
            $(".fixed-header-wrap").fadeOut('fast');
            $('.header-logo').fadeOut('fast');
            $('.header-wrap').removeClass('header-blue');

            scroller = true;
        }

    } else {

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 94 && scroller) {

            $('.fixed-header-wrap').addClass('header-shadow');
            $(".fixed-header-wrap").fadeIn('fast');
            $('.header-wrap').addClass('header-blue');

            scroller = false;

        } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 94 && !scroller) {

            $(".fixed-header-wrap").removeClass('header-shadow');
            $(".fixed-header-wrap").fadeOut('fast');

            scroller = true;
        }

    }

});
```

Is there any reason for this or changes that can be made to make the desired effect work across all browsers?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `$(window).scroll()` to `$('html,body').scroll()`. It worked for me in a previous project... Let me know if it works.